# points not plotting in correct location

Tags: qgis, gps, quickmapservices

I have a csv that I am importing with lat long values amongst others. I select the correct fields for both values and ensure that both the layer and project CRS are set to WSG84(UTM30N)EPSG32630. My points should appear in the UK but are appearing at 1824,645 (south of Liberia).

I have checked my points direct in google (51.069946333,-1.701573167) and they are spot on, when I hover my cursor over the location it reads wrong. I guess I have the wrong reference system set but I understood this was the one needed for GPS.

I am using quickmapservice and googlemaps, QGIS 2.16

Answer (score 4):

If you have coordinates in degrees, you **MUST** use EPSG:4326 for the **LAYER** CRS.

The **PROJECT** CRS can be set different.